# Shapely is no Win32 Application

Tags: python-2.7, shapely

I'm trying to install shapely via pip on Windows. I'm using python 2.7.13 32-bit on 64-bit System. It's because I'm running Mapnik too.

Mapproxy needs Shapely for reading Shapefiles for Seeding Coverages.

Trying to run `pip install shapely` turns into

```
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is no valid Win32-Application
```

pip is trying to install Shapely Version 1.5.17.
When installing version 1.6b4 from tar.gz manually downloaded the installation is working. But mapproxy-seed with shape coverage is not working.

Has anyone a solution?

Thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install from the wheel you can  find [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely), with the command `pip install <path-to-downloaded-file>.whl`